# Problems Setting A Value

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

```
     private function restoreColumns( headerTextArray:ArrayCollection, widthArray:ArrayCollection):void  {
            dg.removeEventListener( IndexChangedEvent.HEADER_SHIFT, this.saveColumns );     
            for (var n:int = 0; n < headerTextArray.length; n++)
            {   
                trace ( "Before: n: " + n + " WA: " + widthArray.getItemAt(n) + " DG: " + dg.columns[n].width);
//              moveColumnTo(String(headerTextArray.getItemAt(n)), n); 
                // Problems copying for the last column
                dg.columns[n].width = 0;    
                trace ( "Middle: n: " + n + " WA: " + widthArray.getItemAt(n) + " DG: " + dg.columns[n].width);
                dg.columns[n].width = widthArray.getItemAt(n);              
                trace ( "After:  n: " + n + " WA: " + widthArray.getItemAt(n) + " DG: " + dg.columns[n].width);
            }   
            dg.addEventListener( IndexChangedEvent.HEADER_SHIFT, this.saveColumns );
        }
```

Here is the trace output of the above code:

```
Before: n: 0 WA: 113 DG: 95
Middle: n: 0 WA: 113 DG: 20
After:  n: 0 WA: 113 DG: 113
Before: n: 1 WA: 71 DG: 85
Middle: n: 1 WA: 71 DG: 20
After:  n: 1 WA: 71 DG: 71
Before: n: 2 WA: 41 DG: 101
Middle: n: 2 WA: 41 DG: 101
After:  n: 2 WA: 41 DG: 101
```

As you can see,

1. I am not able to set dg.columns[2].width to the desired value. [The problem occurs for the last column.]
2. I am also not able to set dg.columns[0].width = 0 before the middle trace.

I initially thought that the moveColumnTo() may have some thing to do with the problem but I am getting the problem even after commenting the call to the function.

What is wrong?

Here is the code that calls restoreColumns. [I just realized that I can edit my original post and add this.]

```
private function processQueryResponse(evt:DWSQLevent):void {
            this.removeEventListener( IndexChangedEvent.HEADER_SHIFT, this.saveColumns );   
            this.removeEventListener( ResizeEvent.RESIZE, this.saveColumns );           
            var headerTextArray:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            var widthArray:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            if ( query.queryMessage == "SELECT" ) {
                if (evt.dataRetrieved == true && query.queryData && query.queryData.length > 0 && query.queryData[0].length > 0 ) {
                    initialColumns = query.queryData[0];
                    var record:Object;
                    for (var n:Number = 0; n< this.columns.length; n++)
                    {
                        record = initialColumns.getItemAt(n);
                        headerTextArray.addItem(record.headertext);
                        widthArray.addItem( record.width );
                    }
                    restoreColumns( headerTextArray, widthArray);
                    haveColumnData = true;
                } else if ( query.queryData.length > 0 && query.queryData[0].length == 0 ){
                    Alert.show( "Problems reading column data from database. Saved column order not restored." );   
                    trace ("Select error / no rows "); // alert moving not done
                }
            } else {
            }   
            this.addEventListener( IndexChangedEvent.HEADER_SHIFT, this.saveColumns );  
            //          this.addEventListener( ResizeEvent.RESIZE, this.saveColumns );
        }
```

Comment: i'm thinking about it right now, but, you can try changing this "number" variable as an "int" variable here: `for (var n:Number = 0; n< this.columns.length; n++)`

Answer (score 0):

it looks you should use `n < widthArray.length` instead of `headerTextArray.length` in your loop condition.

Comment: The two have the same length. [I would like to post the function that calls restoreColumns but it will exceed the character limit for a comment.]

Comment: add to your original post?

Comment: actually it's better you post how're you filling "dg.columns[]" array.
because it looks like this code working but may be a problem in dg.columns[] and "width"s